# PIL Image ImportError

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper, python-imaging-library

I have Pillow and qrcode modules installed in a virtual environment.

From the python shell, I can create a test image programmatically using PIL:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = Image.new('1', (200, 200))
>>> img.save('test-image.jpeg', 'JPEG')
```

Great, that works just as I would expect it to. However, I'm getting this error when I try to use a module that relies on PIL:

```
>>> import qrcode
>>> qr_code = qrcode.make("1") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qrcode/main.py", line 8, in make
     return qr.make_image()
   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qrcode/main.py", line 186, in make_image
     from qrcode.image.pil import PilImage
   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qrcode/image/pil.py", line 5, in <module>
     import Image
ImportError: No module named Image
```

Why can't qrcode import PIL's Image class but it works from the shell?

Comment: This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but… does `from PIL import ImageDraw` also work on the shell? If that module is somehow missing from the `PIL` package, `qrcode` will assume `Image` is also missing from the `PIL` package and try to import it from the top level, which will cause exactly the problem you're seeing.

Comment: A more likely possibility is that you're not actually testing from the right virtual environment. From your shell, after that `from PIL import Image`, just type `Image` and see what path it gives you. Is it inside `/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/env1/blah/blah`, or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with your installation: `Image` module have been installed as subpackage of a `PIL` module, while the library you are using expects `Image` module to be directly in the python path. Simplest solution is to replace:

```
import Image
```

with:

```
from PIL import Image
```

in file `qrcode/image/pil.py`.

Comment: Yeah, old-school PIL sometimes installed one way, sometimes the other. Many people would explicitly add the package to `sys.path` to work around this, but that was always a horrible idea. Pillow picked the more sensible one and went with it consistently, but there are a few other packages out there that expect the other.

Comment: But… this isn't going to work. If you look at [the source](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/blob/master/qrcode/image/pil.py), it already tries `from PIL import Image`, and only falls back to `import Image` when that fails.

Comment: In this case, there must be something wrong with your virtualenv. Just tested and it works: I ran `virtualenv so && source so/bin/activate && pip install pillow qrcode six && python` and typed `import qrcode; qrcode.make("1").show()`. Sorry for the poor, comment-fit formatting.

Comment: I spun up a new vagrant box and did a fresh install of everything and things are working as expected. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.